# vim with ssh and putty ... broken syntax coloring after windows paste

Tags: vim, ssh, syntax-highlighting, putty

**Background:** I was editing a file in vim using putty over ssh. In order to copy a huge section of text to the file from windows, I just used the standard putty paste command.

Now, whenever I edit a file in vim using putty over ssh, the syntax coloring is gone, and it is all replaced with a single-color yellow.

**Question:** Has anyone else out there seen this happen? Is there a best-practice way to diagnose what caused this and fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to refresh your screen by pressing `Ctrl+L`. If that doesn't help try `:syntax sync`. If that doesn't help either try saving file and reloading it using `:e`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried :set paste in vim?